# IPTABLES port 53 closed

Tags: firewall, proxy

I'm configuring my proxy server to serve 2 Internet connections to one end.

The problem is, some websites load and some don't.

My cache.log file return me this when I attempt to load a website:

```
2015/10/30 15:15:03| comm_udp_sendto: FD 8, (family=2) 208.67.222.222:53: (101) Network is unreachable
2015/10/30 15:15:03| idnsSendQuery: FD 8: sendto: (101) Network is unreachable
2015/10/30 15:15:03| comm_udp_sendto: FD 8, (family=2) 208.67.220.220:53: (101) Network is unreachable
2015/10/30 15:15:03| idnsSendQuery: FD 8: sendto: (101) Network is unreachable
```

My firewall script can be seen here: 
http://pastebin.com/9dbiSmeU

Comment: Generally, Network unreachable refers to a routing issue, rather than a port blocking issue.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors in the logs concern a DNS connection (port 53) towards OpenDNS servers (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220).  It appears that these servers are not reachable from your proxy machine.

The issues with websites not loading aren't due to the websites themselves, but to the fact that your proxy is unable to resolve the domain name of the URL to an IP address.  Probably some websites work because their IP mapping is still stored in the DNS cache, which makes me think that the connection to the OpenDNS servers works sometimes.

Try a `traceroute 208.67.222.222` to see where the connection fails.